# FTP Publishing Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, ftp, hosting, publishing

I'm going to host my ASP.NET MVC website in GoDaddy. It says that I have to publish it first before I can host it. I'm following this link (http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-host-your-Asp-Net-mvc-website-on-godaddy-server/) for hosting my website. But when I check the content of my File Manager in my GoDaddy account, some folders of my project is not there (like the App_Data, App_Start, Models) Why is that? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the guide you used to publish your website. On step 16 it said to check "Exclude files from App_Data folder". If you check this App_Data folder does not get published. If you want to publish files in app-data folder then uncheck it while publishing.

Secondly, when a website is published, a .dll file is created for each project, so all your classes in app_start and models folder are already included in that .dll. You can find the .dll file in bin folder by the name of your project.

Comment: I've unchecked "Exclude files from App_Data folder" when I publish my website. But the folder is still not in the my File Manager. And I already looked at my bin folder, but the it's not there.

Comment: Also the Controller folder is not being publish. Why is that? Thank you for the help Sir.

Comment: Do you have any files in app_data folder? if not then it will not get published. 
Controllers are also included in .dll file. 

All classes are compiled into a single dll. So you wont be able to see any .cs class files in published code.

Comment: There's no file in it Sir. So I just manually created an "App_Data" folder. An error after another but thank you for your help Sir. :)